# How to integrate angular 4 with Django

Tags: python, django, angular

I'm trying to integrate Django and Angular 4 in the same app (running as two servers as well).
Well, reading the [setup guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html) I noticed about the references to the `node_modules` directory (and some "hardcode" references).

Well, I wanna know if is possible to merge those technologies, I mean, to use the `Django context` and the `http.get` of angular to bind the results.

Or, those `npm_modules` should are included in my `static` directory?

But, where I should generate the angular project?

Comment: I use Django REST Framework with Angular all the time. I like to serve the Angular app directly from the webserver, there is no need to serve it from Django.

Comment: @PauloScardine how are you handling the sessions? are you using the django authentication method?

Comment: I have used several methods, basic authentication over SSL, session authentication, OAuth2. Each one has their tradeoffs.

Comment: I think ViewFlow.io is based on that concept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is an old thread, but I finally got this to work the way I want/need. I have a Django backend with DRF and I wanted to use Angular 4 for the front end. My app depends on user logins and running two debug servers (one for Django and one for Angular) was not an option for me.

The secret sauce is to run this command:

```
ng build --watch true --output-path <your_static_scripts_dir>
```

I created my Angular app (using `ng new app-name`) inside my Django project, copied the `index.html` into the `templates` directory (and modified it to use my `staticfiles` directory).

Now I can edit my files in PyCharm, the `watch` will recompile the `.ts` files and I only have to run the built-in Django debug server.

Comment: as of `Angular CLI: 1.5.0` `--output-dir` has changed to `--output-path`

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use angular in front-end with nodejs or a parent make an api with Django using DRF or tastypie ... but if you absolutely want to combine the two would have to consider the versions prior to the 2+ I even develop in Django but as we want to be present on the mobile platforms and native also then to the fact of API's or sometimes we pass the weapon to the left using only javascript. But do not forget in the world of technology what really matters is adaptation and agility